# DT in Shiny and R: Custom number formatting

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a shiny-app that displays a datatable using the `DT`-package. What I want is to be able to format columns in a custom way. For example I want a currency value to be displayed like this: 1,234.50€ instead of the `DT`-way, which displays it like this $1,234.5 (notice the change in the symbol, the position of the currency-symbol as well as the numbers after the decimal-point).

An MWE looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  # UI
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),

  # SERVER
  server = function(input, output) {
    dat <- data.frame(cur = 1234.5, # supposed to be displayed as: 1,234.50€ | Bad! 
                                         # displayed as $1,234.5
                      perc = 0.123456, # 12.34% | Good!
                      num = 1000) # 1,000 | Bad! displayed as 1000

    # render DT
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      datatable(dat) %>%
        formatCurrency(c('cur'), "$") %>%
        formatPercentage('perc', 2) %>%
        formatRound('num', digits = 0)
    )
  }
)
```

It does a fairly good job, however, when changing the currency-symbol to `€`, the symbol disappears. When inserting another character like "E", the character is still displayed at the beginning not at the end. Furthermore, the numeric value does not get a "big-mark".

Any ideas?

Comment: For numeric you could try: `formatCurrency('num', currency = "", interval = 3, mark = ",",  digits = 0)`. For Euro, `formatCurrency(c('cur'), currency = "€", interval = 3, mark = ",",  digits = 1)`. I'm not sure how to get it on the right though

Comment: The `formatCurrency`-approach to get 1,000 is good!
However, I still do not see a €-sign for the currency number. Same applies if I use `\U20AC` instead of `€` as suggested in `?formatCurrency`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the position of the currency symbol in the .js file from the datatable package.

Edit the line of the DTWidget.formatCurrency function

```
 $(thiz.api().cell(row, col).node()).html(currency + markInterval(d, interval, mark));
```

to simply

```
 $(thiz.api().cell(row, col).node()).html(markInterval(d, interval, mark) + currency);
```

in the DT/htmlwidgets/datatables.js file in the directory of your R librarys.

As for the € Symbol,

```
formatCurrency(c('cur'), currency = "\U20AC", interval = 3, mark = ",", digits = 2)
```

does work for me, thats what you tried and you don't see any symbol?

Comment: Interesting approach. I would have to copy the library direction to other machines if I want to get the same results right?

Comment: Yeah you would have to link that library to every machine, run on a server only that library of course. Also after every DT package update you would have to adjust the code. So this is kinda gimmiky, you could suggest this to the development team on https://github.com/rstudio/DT to implemend an option in the r code to arrange the currency symbol, as this is very easy to adjust it might get picked up in the next update.

Comment: With regard to the latter solution: 
When I type in `shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {dat <- data.frame(cur = 1234.5)    
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      datatable(dat) %>%
        formatCurrency(c('cur'), currency = "\U20AC", interval = 3, mark = ",",
                       digits = 2)
      )
  }
)` I get an error that `digits` is an unused argument... 
Without the `digits` argument I still do not see the currency symbol. [See Here](http://puu.sh/kShhA/0398a4e597.png)

Comment: Hm, that is kinda strange, your code runs fine on my windows machine and ubuntu server. My package versions are dplyr_0.4.2      DT_0.1.34        shiny_0.12.2 with R version 3.2.2, maybe you have to update your packages? ( use sessionInfo() to check your loaded versions )

Comment: I use R version 3.2.2, DT_0.1 (latest CRAN release), shiny 0.12.2 in RStudio 0.99.482 on Windows 7 SP1 64bit. The system language is German, therefore UTF-8 should be working, especially the € sign

Comment: Hm, maybe try the development version of DT: devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT') .

Comment: Still no € sign. I suspect it has something to do with my machine instead of the R-code... Thank you anyway!